# How to upgrade to 10.5.1 using Azure Cloud Builder

Tags: arcgis-10.5, arcgis-enterprise, azure

I installed ArcGIS Enterprise 10.5 in Azure using the Azure Cloud Builder, now I need to upgrade my portal to 10.5.1. How can I upgrade to 10.5.1 using Cloud Builder or do I have to manually upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, deployments built with the Azure Cloud Builder can be manually upgraded just as you do on-premises installations.

For 10.5 to 10.5.1, this should not cause any issues on Azure.  However, depending on your IT recovery strategy, you may want to do this on a staging environment first or make use of Azure Cloud Backup so you can roll back if you encounter any issues.

Run the upgrade in the following order:
Perform the upgrade steps for each ArcGIS Enterprise software component in the following order:

- Portal for ArcGIS
- ArcGIS Web Adaptor (for Portal)
- ArcGIS Server (upgrade hosting server first, then any other servers)
- ArcGIS Web Adaptor (for Server)
- ArcGIS Data Store (upgrade primary first, then stand-by)

**Further Reading:**

- [ArcGIS Updates & Azure](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/cloud/azure/arcgis-updates-and-microsoft-azure.htm)
- [Upgrade ArcGIS Enterprise](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/get-started/latest/windows/upgrade-arcgis-enterprise.htm)

// EDIT

As of 10.6, the builder now supports upgrades. Check [this video.](https://youtu.be/iAge4J0toG4?t=751)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the manual upgrade procedure - you can make use of Azure Cloud builder to upgrade dot-versions. IE. From 10.6 to 10.6.1

If you've deployed 10.6, you'd need to get the 10.6.1 version of Cloud Builder. Running against your instance you'd have the option to upgrade.

This has been explained in the [upgrade deployment](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/cloud/azure/upgrade-azure-deployments.htm) help topic. Note - this topic is only available for 10.6/10.6.1, inferring that the 10.5 to 10.5.1 must be done manually.